# Funny error with db:populate and I18n : fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, populate, rails-i18n

I'm following M. Hartl tutorial, and I have an error I can't understand. I want to populate my database with fake users, using first `rake db:reset` and then the `rake db:populate`, but it fails.

Here is the code :

**lib/tasks/sample_data.rake**

```rb
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@apptesting.com",
                 password: "motdepasse",
                 password_confirmation: "motdepasse",
                 admin: true)
    99.times do |n|
      name  = "User #{n+1}"
      email = "user-#{n+1}@apptesting.com"
      password  = "motdepasse"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

**Result after `rake db:populate`**

```rb
$ rake db:populate --trace
** Invoke db:populate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:populate
rake aborted!
translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.beta1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:41:in `create!'
/home/flo/RoR/letroquet/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/flo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:populate
```

Is there someone who can understand this gibberish and explain it to me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this file: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml in your **config/locales/** folder, it's simply saying that your record is invalid, but it cant find appropriate message in fr. locale

Comment: what do you mean by "but that's all"? is that solved your problem?

Comment: No, it didn't solved anything. I have the same gibberish but `translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid` is replaced by the French translation...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have validation error. Check your User model for validations and try find one that fails.

If you can't find which one validation fails just try create user from console with same attributes.

```
user = User.new({ 'Your attributes' })
user.valid?
user.errors.messages
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your admin attribute is wrong. You can't mass-assign admin unless you added it to `attr_accessible`. If you did add it thats a bad security flaw. Basically anyone could make themselves an admin through the command line. Here is how you add admin to be true:

```
admin.toggle!(:admin)
```

Try that out and let me know if it worked

Comment: Using lib/tasks/sample_data.rake seems not be concerned by mass-assignment. I discovered that ingenious utility [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=4.0#sec-sample_users).